# check if class does not exist on any of data- items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of div elements with a data-windows attribute:

I basically want to check if any of these are not hidden (and doing something if they are all hidden)

I'm looping through them like so, this works but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way:

```
 $("[data-windows]").each(function () {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
         isSomethingShown = true;
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:visible` pseudo selector :

```
if($("[data-windows]:visible").length){
    //Atleast 1 is visible
}else{
    //All hiden
}
```

or

```
var isSomethingShown = !!$("[data-windows]:visible").length; // Bang!Bang! [!!] convert into a boolean
```

Of course, if you want to explicitly check the class, both selector can be change to (and maybe should be for faster performance) `$("[data-windows].hidden")`

Comment: would $("div[data-windows].hidden") be a little faster? or something like $('#overallID').find("div[data-windows].hidden") be better

Comment: Yes at work we had this tested as well and using a id then find is faster than targeting a class. Anyway, we are talking milliseconds but for something big, it will make some difference

Comment: @Huangism Of course, the bigger the DOM is, the faster ID is since when it find 1, it stop searching.

Answer (score 2):

how bout this oneliner:

```
return $("[data-windows].hidden").length == 0 ? false : true;
```

Comment: oh boo, sry...  ill replace with length  done @A.Wolff sry lol

Comment: is there any difference between div[..] and just [..] ?

Comment: yep - its about qualifying selectors.. if you have say an image + a div that has [data-windows] you might want to qualify the selector to only use divs' so thats where youd have $("Div[data-windows].hidden") which would ignore img's with that data

Comment: so in this particular case it would be a little faster if we add the div in front

Comment: maybe a tiny tiny bit yeah but in general i dont think it matters too much.. i guess thats one for a performance tester but id say it'd only really matter if theres alot of stuff on screen.. generally these selectors work very very fast.